# CheckedListBox throwing argument out of range when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

This is a .NET 3.5 Winforms project.

I'm having a weird error trying to programmatically check the checkboxes in checkboxlist.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cBListForming.Items.Add((i + 1).ToString());
    cBListForming.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

So it adds 5 items, from 1 to 5, and then have the added checkboxes checked by default. Nothing surprising.

On the first iteration of the loop, everything works fine but on the second iteration (i == 1), SetItemChecked throws an exception.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRange {"Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter
>   name: index"}

I can see the first checkbox checked visually as well. The rest of them aren't because of the above exception.

This is pretty baffling. Just for testing purposes, I tried to add the items first, and programmatically check them later with a second loop, but still the same issue happens, **even though the count of the checkbox is 5.**

I tried using SetItemCheckState instead. Again, same issue.

I think I might've broken the CheckedListBox component itself, or some weird framework bug that I've encountered.

Any insights to what's going on here would be really appreciated.

Comment: I tried running your code without adding cbList and no errors so perhaps there is something else going on that you may be overlooking I ran the code in your for loop sounds like a designer error when you either added or removed controls

Comment: have you implemented any event to catch CheckedChanged or something which gets fire when you change the checkState of checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty frustrating, but it actually did turn out to be a framework bug (Maybe Winforms Designer had a hiccup).

Removing and readding the checkedlistbox in the designer made it work. No other changes.

Comment: Thank you for your post. That was exact the same problem I had. I copied the CheckedListBox on the designer because of layout reasons. Although the count said that way more items where in the list, it had thrown the exception around the index count the box i copied it from probably has.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cBListForming.Items.Add((i + 1).ToString(), true);
}
```

Comment: Similar issue. First one gets added (and is also checked), but throws argumentoutofrange on the second iteration.

Comment: Would you please mention any Properties/Events utilized for this control?

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming "cBListForming" is a checkbox list.

Check the number of checkboxlist you have. This might be the cause of the problem.

```
cBListForming.Count();
```

Comment: Please read the question.. I've explicitly stated the following : *even though the count of the checkbox is 5.*.

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't noticed the BOLD text. My bad. Just want to ask, are you using "a list of checkboxes" or the control CheckListbox  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx